# What does MKBS mean?

Tags: capacitor, identification

I found some WIMA MKBS capacitors, not a dielectric I have seem before.  WIMA has not been helpful so far (nor Google).  Any idea what MKBS means?

Comment: Robert, you may not be aware there are many plastic film caps in stock at major distributors like D-K, Mouser. What property specs do you need ?

Comment: e.g.  http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/capacitors/film-capacitors/131088?k=&pkeyword=&pv13=205&FV=340045%2C3400cd%2C3400da%2C3400e0%2C340225%2C340289%2C340487%2C3405b7%2C34061b%2C14300003%2C14300004%2C14300005%2C14300007%2C14300008%2C1430000b%2C1430000d%2C1430000e%2C1430000f%2C14300010%2C14300011%2C14300013%2C14300015%2C14300017%2C14300018%2C14300019%2C1430001b%2C14300047%2C14300063%2C1430007b%2C1430009f%2C143000a7%2C1f140000%2Cfff40002%2Cfff80010&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=3&page=1&stock=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=500

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, they are obsolete "Metallized polycarbonate capacitors". Not sure how critical is your application, so you may or may not want to trust an [ebay listing](http://www.ebay.de/itm/4-Stueck-MKBS-High-End-Folienkondensatoren-6-8-F-100V-Wima-die-Legende-lebt-/111257107623).

[image]

I also found [this](http://datasheet.datasheetarchive.com/originals/scans/Scans-069/DSA2IH00244849.pdf) datasheet for MKB3 and MKB5 capacitors. May be useful, may be not.

Comment: Thanks to all you folks who answered my question.  Ebay is the one place I didn't think to look.

Answer (score 3):

These are polycarbonate film capacitors, which can operate at higher temperatures.  The manufacturers of the polycarbonate film discontinued making it many years ago, but there are alternatives.  See the links below:

[Discussion of polycarbonate film cap replacements](http://powerelectronics.com/content/there-substitute-polycarbonate-film-capacitors)

And from Wima:

[Wima discussion of same](http://www.wima.com/EN/polycarbonate.htm)